# C# LINQ Left Outer Join for XML doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, xml, linq, outer-join

I'm trying to do a **Left Outer Join** for two XMLs and get another XML(not a collection!) as an output, but LINQ's query 'into' seems to be extracting only values but not full elements with all the original tags and attributes.

My **xml1** looks like this:

```
<tag>
  <abc id="zxy">tiger</abc>
  <abc id="zzz">rabbit</abc>
</tag>
```

My **xml2**:

```
<tag>
  <aaa attr1="1" attr2="zzz">value1</aaa>
  <aaa attr1="2" attr2="zxc">value2</aaa>
</tag>
```

My code in C#:

```
var que= from first in xml1
         join second in xml2
         on (string)first.Attribute(attr1) equals (string)second.Attribute(attr2) into temp
         from tmpL in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
         orderby (string)first.Attribute(attr1)//, (string)tmpL.Attribute(attr2) -- this one isn't working because it's not an element
         select new XElement("child", first, tmpL == null ? String.Empty : (string)tmpL);

var final= new XDocument(new XElement("parent", que));
```

This is what I get joining two above XMLs using that code:

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <abc id="zxy">tiger</abc>value1</child>
  <child>
    <abc id="zzz">rabbit</abc>value2</child>
</parent>
```

As you can see it's an invalid XML with value1 and value2 stick to the sibling elements, whereas they should be wrapped in their own original tags (with their original attributes): `<aaa attr1="1" attr2="zzz">value1</aaa>` and `<aaa attr1="2" attr2="zxc">value2</aaa>` correspondingly.

Thus I can't use .Attribute() and other things on them.
Also I can't just insert these values inside of newly created elements, because I need attributes from the original elements in xml2.

Can you please help me to get the following XML?

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <abc id="zxy">tiger</abc>
    <aaa attr1="1" attr2="zzz">value1</aaa>
  </child>
  <child>
    <abc id="zzz">rabbit</abc>
    <aaa attr1="2" attr2="zxc">value2</aaa>
  </child>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"..but LINQ's query 'into' seems to be extracting only values but not full elements with all the original tags and attributes"*

You actually got the `XElement`s as expected, but then it was explicitly cast to `string` which cause only the string value retained, here :

```
select new XElement("child", first, tmpL == null ? String.Empty : (string)tmpL);
```

Remove casting and simply pass `null` instead of `String.Empty` when you want nothing to be the child of the newly created `child` element :

```
select new XElement("child", first, tmpL == null ? null : tmpL);
```

or simply pass `tmpL` no matter it is `null` or not, which yield in an equivalent yet cleaner statement :

```
select new XElement("child", first, tmpL);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! The only remaining thing is orderby, that I pointed in my initial comment: `orderby (string)first.Attribute(attr1)//, (string)tmpL.Attribute(attr2) -- this one isn't working because it's not an element`. I removed `string` before `tmpL.Attribute(attr2)`, but still it says that it's not an instance of the object Is there a way to use it for ordering?